# What is the origin of white mourning clothes in African-American culture?

Tags: united-states, tradition, black-history

I've noticed that in pictures from the funerals of George Floyd and Rayshard Brooks, a large number of attendees are wearing white. I've found a few resources online that suggest this is a specifically African-American tradition, but I'd like to know about its origins and the reasons behind it. Where did this tradition originate?

Some of my sources:

[Forum post](https://www.city-data.com/forum/general-u-s/2442512-interesting-observations-attending-african-american-funeral-5.html)

[Rayshard Brooks's funeral](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/06/23/us/rayshard-brooks-funeral/index.html) (in the photos of his family, not of the pallbearers)

[George Floyd's funeral](https://www.cnn.com/2020/06/10/us/george-floyd-wednesday-updates/index.html)

I have also found mentions in the "Encyclopedia of Cross-cultural Psychology" but I'm having trouble pulling it up on mobile and will add it when I can later.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on ["Mourning"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mourning) mentions many other cultural contexts where white is worn.

Comment: Just a quick thanks for updating the question to include sources.  Welcome to the site and I look forward to the answer.